# Отправка сообщений пользователям

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такой момент,нужно отправить сообщение сразу 5 пользователям в системе,и после этого каждому на почту выслать письмо с темой вида 'У вас новое сообщение...'.Добавлять этих 5 юзеров в бд в цикле как по мне плохая практика, можно добавить сразу одним запросом 5-ых,но тогда я не смогу получить айди каждого.Как решаются такие моменты?

Comment: Если нужно знать id каждой записи, то insert в цикле вполне нормальное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно - добавить юзеров одним INSERT-м, а следующим за ним SELECT-м - извлечь идентификаторы?

Comment: Как я получу идентификаторы всех пользователей если добавлю сразу одним инсертом всех? Или вы предлагаете сделать запрос на выбор последних 5 пользователей?

Comment: Грубо говоря- ты знаешь данные пользователей, которых добавил, а значит - можешь проделать SELECT по ним. Что-то типа "INSERT INTRO users (name) VALUES (UserNames)", "SELECT id FROM users WHERE name IN (UserNames);"

Comment: А вообще - не думаю, что это тот случай, из-за которого стоит заморачиваться. Таки читабельнее будет вариант с циклом.

Comment: А если сделать такой момент? 

select *
from users 
order by users.id desc limit 5

Comment: И при выполнении второго экземпляра скрипта параллельно (маловероятно, но всё же) - получить неверные данные.